# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on Android4.4 without Multi-Dex

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Xamarin Android app who targets Android 6.0 and has minimal version 4.4.
On 6.0 and up it runs without any issues. But on my Android 4.4 test device it crashes after our SetupWizard in the app when it should register the jobs with the message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Whole Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.postkca.friendsappdate/connectContacts.droid.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md5e63ccdb150b7ea0bbd5c3cb0d08710a0.FetchContactupdatesJob
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md5e63ccdb150b7ea0bbd5c3cb0d08710a0.FetchContactupdatesJob
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
    at connectContacts.droid.activities.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at connectContacts.droid.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md5e63ccdb150b7ea0bbd5c3cb0d08710a0/FetchContactupdatesJob
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5e63ccdb150b7ea0bbd5c3cb0d08710a0.FetchContactupdatesJob" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.postkca.friendsappdate-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.postkca.friendsappdate-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    ... 18 more
```

I saw a lot of posts who had similar issues, but all of them had MultiDex enabled which I do not have. Also Xamarin linking is set to None and the exception is the same with or without ProGuard.
What can this cause?

EDIT1: add screenshot of build configuration

[image]

FetchContactUpdatesJob:

```
[Service(Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
    public class FetchContactupdatesJob : JobService
    {
        private const int JOB_ID = 10;

        public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await FetchContactupdates(args));
            return true;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters args)
        {
            return true;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, Android.App.StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            var messenger = (Messenger)intent.GetParcelableExtra("messenger");

            SendMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_SERVICE_FETCH_CONTACTUPDATES, messenger);

            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }

        private void SendMessage(int what, Messenger messenger)
        {
            var message = Message.Obtain();

            message.What = what;
            message.Obj = this;

            try
            {
                messenger.Send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private async Task FetchContactupdates(JobParameters args)
        {
           // Service Code

            JobFinished(args, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Schedules the task for execution.
        /// </summary>
        public void ScheduleTask()
        {
            var builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,
                                              new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(FetchContactupdatesJob))));
            // Execute all 15 Minutes
            builder.SetPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000);
            builder.SetPersisted(true);
            builder.SetRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.None);
            builder.SetRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
            builder.SetRequiresCharging(false);

            var tm = (JobSchedulerType)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            var status = tm.Schedule(builder.Build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `FetchContactupdatesJob` constructor. I recall to have seen `ClassNotFoundException` when something goes wrong on constructor

Comment: Is `md5e63ccdb150b7ea0bbd5c3cb0d08710a0.FetchContactupdatesJob` on your main dex list? `classes.dex` or overfill `classes{n}.dex` in your `obj/{configuration}/android/bin` folder?

Comment: @JonDouglas I only have a classes.dex. But I haven't yet found out how to open it

Comment: See "classyshark" on my blog: http://www.jon-douglas.com/2017/03/15/apk-tools/

Comment: I apologize, I thought the title said "with" multidex. Anyway, still check to ensure this class is in the `classes.dex` first.

Comment: ah, classy shark worked. But the class in question is on it.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I tried to make some breakpoints, but somehow none is hit even though I activated the debuging for release builds. ( I should add that the issue only occurs on release, not on debug)

Comment: I do remember to have seen this problem with UI controls on Android when contructor fails, not sure if the same applies for non UI classes. Do you have any logic in the constructor that could fail? I'd try to comment out all logic in there to test.

Comment: No, there is just the default constructor.

Comment: Are you 100% sure linker is disabled? The only other option that comes to my mind is the linker to be removing that class.... but you said it's set to `None`... it would be also hard to explain why the problem only exist on 4.4 if the linker is to blame. Have you done a clean build just in case?/

Comment: I added a screenshot of how I build.

Comment: Cleaned the solution, deleted the bin and obj folder and tried again. But still the crash.

Comment: What type of class is `FetchContactupdatesJob`? How is it declared?

Comment: If you have a minimal viable reproduction, I think that's your next step assuming the linker is off and this is found in your dex list. We will want to know what type of class this is as it might not be properly declared in your application.

Comment: @SushiHangover I added the code from the FetchContactupdatesJob to my original post.

Comment: @JonDouglas that's a good idea. I guess that's the next thing I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JobService` was added in `API 21`:

Re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html

Android 4.4/KitKat is `API 19` so the error makes sense as that device does not support `JobService`.

There are Java-based libraries, like the Evernote's OSS [`android-job`](https://github.com/evernote/android-job), that can be bound in an `Xamarin.Android` library that abstract the API levels used to schedule jobs... Otherwise you might want to look at the code to see how they handle the different APIs and do the same in your app.